# Chaining calculation on click - problem with multiply and divide

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, calculator

Currently i'm working on React calculator. Slowly but surely I'm about to finish this project ,but today I have noticed this Math logic error.

**Example**

> 2+2*5 - returns 20 but should return 12 ,because multiplication is of course preferred.

**Function which is called after every click on operator button**

```
function operator(e){
let newOperator='';
let oldOperator=number.operator;
let result;

if(number.firstNumber && number.operator && number.secondNumber){
  newOperator = e.target.name;

  if(oldOperator === '+'){
    result = Number(number.firstNumber) + Number(number.secondNumber);
  }

  if(oldOperator === 'x'){
    result = Number(number.firstNumber) * Number(number.secondNumber);
  }
  
  if(oldOperator === '-'){
    result = Number(number.firstNumber) - Number(number.secondNumber);
  }
  
  if(oldOperator === '/'){
    result = Number(number.firstNumber) / Number(number.secondNumber);
  }

  setNumber(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    firstNumber:result,
    displayed:result,
    operator:newOperator,
    secondNumber:''
  }))

}else{
  let operator = e.target;
  setNumber(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    operator:operator.name
  }))
  turnOnOrange(operator);
}
```

There is nothing bad with this function and it works great, except that logical problem with multiply and probably with division too. I know the problem is every time i press new operator button and condition is fulfilled function make it's calculation a push it to state. So like in the Example above ,function first adds 2+2 and result of that multiplies by 5.

I've tried to fix this by creating specific If conditions ,variables and using prevState of second number ,because after every operation(no matter if + - * or / ) secondNumber state is set to empty, and result is pushed to firstNumber state.because of possibility of chaining.

for example

```
let oldOperator = number.operator;
let newOperator = event.target.name;
if(oldOperator === '+' && newOperator === 'x'){
    result = Number(number.firstNumber) + Number(number.prevNum) * Number(number.secondNumber);
}
```

But It also didn't work. I think it is just logical problem with those conditions and I can't figure it out how to write it correct.

**Codesandbox link**

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cannon-l5kbt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `eval()` function. This function will do the calculation for you.

Therefore you have to put the whole equation in the `eval` function.

```js
const equation = "2+2*5"
console.log(eval(equation))
```

Comment: I’ve did some research on Google before i asked here and eval isn’t good solution for this and it keeps throwing me errors after little bit of chaining. That is the reason why I made several states like firstNumber ,secondNumber ,etc. and it is more safe to work with them separated and work with numbers and operators just like I’m working.

Comment: If you are putting in a valid equation the eval function will work fine.